# How do I delete all child elements using linq to sql?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there an easy way to delete all child records for an item using Linq to sql?

Comment: What do you mean by child?  Are you wanting to delete child references, objects or descendants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this will work if there is a relationship between the tables:

```
var parent = // ...
context.Children.DeleteAllOnSubmit(parent.Children);
context.SubmitChanges();
```